# разбиения столбца DataFrame на два по строке-разделителю

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть столбец `df[col]` который имеет вид "x на сумму yyy yyy руб." 
нужно разбить столбец на два - `df[col1]` в котором будут одни `x` или `NaN` и `df[col2]` в котором будут `'yyy yyy руб.'`

```
closed_executions_count = pd.Series()
closed_executions_sum = pd.Series()
list_of_words=[]
for n in df_common_fin['r_data_executions_blocks_0_sum']:
    list_of_words.append(str(n).split(sep=' на сумму '))
```

Код выдает ошибку

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only
>   pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
                       col
0  x на сумму 123 456 руб.
1      y на сумму 999 руб.
2    blah-blah-blah 1 руб.
```

Решение:

```
In [11]: df[['new1','new2']] = df['col'].str.split('\s*на сумму\s*', expand=True)
```

Результат:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
                       col                   new1          new2
0  x на сумму 123 456 руб.                      x  123 456 руб.
1      y на сумму 999 руб.                      y      999 руб.
2    blah-blah-blah 1 руб.  blah-blah-blah 1 руб.          None
```